# i3wm / debian accent marks

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout

I have the next problem: I'm using a USA keyboard using that distribution, but I'm a spanish speaker, so I need to configure the keyboard to somehow print the characters I need (`é`, `á`, `í`, `ó`, `ú`, `ñ`, `Ñ`).
The solution I thought was to make use of the i3wm keybinding, by using for example alt+shift+a to print á character. Anybody knows how can I make it? Or if there's a better / fast / different solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using the international (`intl`) variant of the `us` layout instead of some complex workaround. You can temporarily (until logout) set it with

```
setxkbmap us -variant intl
```

To set it permanently on Debian, you have to modify `/etc/default/keyboard` and set the variables `XKBLAYOUT` and `XKBVARIANT` accordingly:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="intl"
```

You can also run `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration; service keyboard-setup restart`. See the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard) for more information.

---

The `intl` variant is mostly identical to the standard `us` layout, with some key differences:

- The right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is now <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, which acts much like the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key in that it generates different characters, when pressed in conjunction with other keys (*ISO_Level3_Shift*). It can also be combined with <kbd>Shift</kbd> to write yet another set of characters.

  - <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> prints "á", <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> prints "Á". Similarly for <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>u</kbd>.
  - <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> prints "ñ", <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> prints "Ñ".
  - All other alpha-numeric and symbol keys also print additional characters, when combined with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
- *Dead keys*: these keys do not generate a character on their own, instead output depends on the next key that is pressed:

  - *circumflex* (" ^ ", <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>): Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd> will print as "â". Other combinations like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd> will print nothing. To print "^" either press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> twice or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>.
  - *grave* aka *backtick* (" ` ", <kbd>`</kbd>):  <kbd>`</kbd> followed by <kbd>e</kbd> will get you "è"
  - *tilde* (" ~ ", <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>): <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> will print "Ñ".
- Some changed keys:

  - *apostrophe* aka *quote* (" ' ", <kbd>'</kbd>) is replaced by (dead) *acute* (" ´ "): Pressing <kbd>'</kbd> followed by <kbd>i</kbd> will print "í". To print an " ' ", you need to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> (<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> is the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key)
  - *double quote* (" " ", <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>) is replaced by (dead) *diaeresis*: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> followed by <kbd>o</kbd> prints "ö". To print " " ", you need to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>.
  - *less* (" < ", <kbd><</kbd>) and *greater* (" > ", <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>) now print " \ " and " | " instead. You can still type " < " by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and " > " by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I use *dvorak* in english layout over a latin american keyboard. To change within layouts inside **i3wm** I use *mate-settings-daemon*.

[image: i3/config file]

Then with *mate-keyboard-properties* you could configure as you wish. In my case, when press the two CTRL keys.

If you run **i3wm** over GNOME instead of MATE, put *gnome-settings-daemon* in the config file `~/.config/i3/config`.